# How does the standard proof that IP is in PSPACE apply to, say, the graph non-isomorphism problem?

Tags: graph-isomorphism, interactive-proof-systems

I learned years ago that $IP \subseteq PSPACE$ since you could simulate all sets of messages and then determine the probability of success. But lately I’ve been looking at [the standard proof of this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_(complexity)#IP_%E2%8A%86_PSPACE) and I'm having trouble with it.

Basically, I don't understand how we can apply this proof to zero-knowledge settings. For instance, how do we compute the probability of P giving an accepting answer when the protocol tells us nothing about the function or its input.

I've tried building out the tree for the graph non-isomorphism problem, but it seems I'm making a mistake because when I try to follow the procedure in the wikipedia article I always get a value of 1, regardless of what input I use. That said, it seems to work fine for, say, the standard proof that $PSPACE \subseteq IP$.

Perhaps what I’m really looking for is the message tree for the graph non-isomorphism problem, since I have evidently built it wrong. Thanks!